# aparecer uma mensagem quando a conexão cair

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho um web-based system desenvolvido em PHP, porém gostaria de que aparecesse uma mensagem como ocorre no Outlook e Facebook quando a conexão cair. Em PHP fiz da seguinte forma:

```
if(!$sock = fsockopen('www.google.com.br',80,$num,$error,5)){
  // Aqui apareceria a mensagem em bootstrap.
}
```

Porém não está funcionando. Quando cai a conexão, aparece aquela página de erro do navegador.

Comment: O php é uma linguagem que corre do lado do servidor é não do lado do ciente. Por isso se a ligação cair é claro que corta a ligação com o servidor onde esse php é executado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A única forma de fazer o que esta querendo é do lado do cliente e não do lado do servidor.

Tem aqui um exemplo em Javascript para detectar se a pagina esta ou não online no momento que é carregada:

```
if(navigator.onLine) { // true|false
    // ...
}
```

Este outro exemplo é executada a função se o Browser ficar offline/online

```
//função a ser executada quando ficar online
function statusOnline() {
    //o seu código...
}

//função a ser executada quando ficar offline
function statusOffline() {
    //o seu código...
}

window.addEventListener('online',  statusOnline);
window.addEventListener('offline', statusOffline);
```

Outra solução pode ser usar uma libreria como [offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)